# Functions not passing self within classes

Tags: python

I am trying to create a class which has functions within it that will be called within a later method in the class, that do not have self passed into the function. Here is my current code, but the python IDLE is brings up errors about Vbond not being defined.

```
class Ozone(descent.Descent):
    def __init__(self, intervals):
        super(Ozone,self).__init__(intervals)
        self.Leq = 1.25
        self.phieq = 2.11
        self.kbond = 20.
        self.kbend = 12.

    def Vbond(L):
        return self.kbond*(((self.Leq/(math.sqrt(2)-L))**4)-((self.Leq/(math.sqrt(2)-L)**2)))

    def Vbend(phi):
        return self.kbend*((phi-self.phieq)**2)*((phi-0.5(math.pi-self.phieq))**2)

    def f(self, x):  # x[0] = L, x[1] = phi
        Vtot = Vbond(2.*x[0]*math.sin(x[1]/2)) + 2.*(Vbond(x[0])) + \
               + Vbend(x[1]) + Vbend((2*math.pi-x[1])/2.)
```

Comment: For starters your indentation is broken, please edit your question to fix that.

Comment: `Vbond` and `Vbend` both refer to `self`.  How do you think you'll be able to get away with not passing `self` to them?

Comment: Python is not Java/C++ where you have "internal" access to "this". Every method that is supposed to work on an object **has to** use self as a first argument, period. If you create a method which does not operate on an object and is simply a function in the scope of the class, you can always declare it as a `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod` (and pass a reference to class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python always passes the object to its instance methods. That reference is how the method can access its own object data. Traditionally we call this variable `self` but its not a requirement of the language. When you define a method like this:

```
def Vbond(L):
    return self.kbond*(((self.Leq/(math.sqrt(2)-L))**4)-((self.Leq  /(math.sqrt(2)-L)**2)))
```

you've defined a method whose object reference is called `L` and takes no additional parameters. Just change it to include `self` in the traditional manner.

```
def Vbond(self, L):
    return self.kbond*(((self.Leq/(math.sqrt(2)-L))**4)-((self.Leq/(math.sqrt(2)-L)**2)))
```

Additionally, you need to use `self` to tell python which object you are refering to when you call its instance methods.

```
Vtot = self.Vbond(2.*x[0]*math.sin(x[1]/2)) + 2.*(self.Vbond(x[0])) + \
           + self.Vbend(x[1]) + self.Vbend((2*math.pi-x[1])/2.)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
def Vbond(L):
```

for

```
def Vbond(self, L):
```

... and same for Vbend function:

```
def Vbend(self, phi):
```